# Dependency Between Objects on Different Boards

Tags: jsxgraph

I am hoping to use 2 different boards and make elements of one dependent on elements on the other board. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, boards can be connected by `board1.addChild(board2)`. Then, every update of `board1` triggers an update of `board2`. Here is a simple example (see it live at https://jsfiddle.net/vcL7aepo/6/):

```
var board1 = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard('box1', {
                boundingbox: [-5, 5, 5, -5],
                axis: false,
                showNavigation: false
          });
var board2 = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard('box2', {
                boundingbox: [-5, 5, 5, -5],
                axis: true,
                showNavigation: false
          });

board1.addChild(board2);
var a = board1.create('slider', [[-3,1], [3,1], [-10,1,10]]);
var f = board2.create('functiongraph', [
        function(x) { return a.Value()*x*x;} 
    ]);
```